# Could not observe my view animation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-animation, thread-sleep

What I suppose to do is , move(translate) an object from one position to another , but using this following method specifically. And,it is somewhat working as need , but what is happening is , I am not able to see the real time change .

The screen appears blank , for some time , and then object is shown , when it reaches its final coordinates on the android screen.

I want to see the real time change.Can you please let me know , where am I going wrong ?

**Java File**

```
package com.example.actualanimation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_id);

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            im.setY(im.getY()+1);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print("Done");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

My assumption is that , when "**Thread.sleep(10)**" is called , it takes the main thread into sleep mode , and this happens for the next 100 loops.And,then finally when the loop execution ends , the object gets showed in final state.

**XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.actualanimation.MainActivity" >

   <ImageView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/img_id"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use view position to animate your views. All you need to animate views in Android is a defining xml file and then use it in `startAnimation` method of view as described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html.

Comment: You are talking about the tween animation . I am aware of that type of Animation . Hence , I mentioned even in my question , that what is the possible reason for such an output ?

Comment: Then you can use timer class to animate your view position to get rid of for with Thread.sleep().

Comment: You call Thread.sleep() on main UI thread, that's really bad idea. All UI are drawn there and you allow it do nothing because of sleep.